# Binary relations concerning $\geq, >, =$

Tags: logic

We first define a binary relation $\geq$.

Then define $>$ by $x>y \iff x\geq y \ \&\  \neg y\geq x$

and $=$ by $x=y \iff x\geq y \ \&\ y\geq x$

By this definition, $x>y$ is not equivalent to $\neg y\geq x$, but they should be... Similarly, if we define $<$ as the negation of $\geq$, then it is not consistent with $>$. What am I missing here? Which property am I missing here that should give rise to the usual notion of $>,\geq, <, \leq$?

By this way, the context is the social science, social choice theory to be exact.

Comment: Your argument fails when you say "$x>y$ is not equivalent to $\neg y\geq x$, but they should be..." . Actually they need not to be logically equivalent! They are only in the case when $\ge $ is a total order.

Comment: I'd consider first order logic with the equality predicate.

Comment: Well, you don't tell us much about the order.  there are [Partial Orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#:~:text=Formally%2C%20a%20partial%20order%20is,the%20end%20of%20the%20chain)., such as inclusion among the subsets of a given set.  For those, you still have the usual relation rules, but two elements needs not be comparable.

Answer (score 1):

The standard axioms for $\leq$ are as follows:

- $\forall x,\quad x\leq x$;
- if $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ then $x=y$;
- if $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$ then $x\leq z$.

This is called a partial order. An example is the subsets of a fixed set, with $A\leq B$ if $a\subseteq B$. Now for this example it is not true that $A\subset B$ is the same as $B\not\subseteq A$, for example try $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$.

What you want will only be true on the assumption that any two objects are comparable, i.e. you also have the axiom

- $\forall x,y,\quad (x\leq y)\vee(y\leq x)$;

this makes a total order.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equivalent in general. Consider empty order on two elements: $\{x, y\}$ with relation $\{\langle x, x\rangle, \langle y, y\rangle\}$ - ie $x \leq x$ and $y \leq y$, but neither $x \leq y$ nor $y \leq x$. Then $\neq x \leq y$, but not $x > y$.

If the order is [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), then we have in addition $x \geq y \vee y \geq x$, so $\neg y \geq x$ now imples $x \geq y$ and $x > y$ becomes equivalent to $\neg y \geq x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming total order,

$$x\ge y\land \lnot(y\ge x)$$ is equivalent to $$x>y.$$

I wonder why you tell the opposite. (Note that the term $x\ge y$ is useless.)

---

$$1\ge 2\land \lnot(2\ge 1)\text{ is false, like }1>2$$

$$1\ge 1\land \lnot(1\ge 1)\text{ is false, like }1>1$$

$$2\ge 1\land \lnot(1\ge 2)\text{ is true, like }2>1$$